# MySQL query for counting users unread message

Tags: mysql, join

I am **sending the notification message to multiple devices**. **User can login from multiple devices.** I have separate table which maintains the device ids of each user. When I send the notification, **I will put an entry on the message_data with userid, message etc.**, I will put an entry on the message_status table for each user device.

So that I can maintain each device **notification sent status** and error.

```
message_data
id          INT     
userid      VARCHAR
message     VARCHAR
sent_time   DATETIME
language    TINYINT

message_status
id              INT
data_id         INT
device_id       VARCHAR
device_type     TINYINT
sent_time       DATETIME
status          TINYINT
error_code      TINYINT (If there is any error, we will have the error code here)
```

**I want to get the unread notification message count for each user.** status field 0 represents , the message for this device is not yet read by user. If it is 1, User have read the message.

**A user can login from multiple devices, If user reads the message in at-least one device, It should be considered as notification message is read.**

If the notification message is not read by user in any device, It needs to be considered as unread message.

How to identify the users with unread notification message count ? Any Idea on this ?

Comment: You need to find if there's another message_status with status = 1 so either use a JOIN or a NOT EXISTS with `WHERE device_id = <devid> AND status = <read>`.

Comment: @mroman I need to get the unread message count by userid. User can  have many registered devices.

Comment: is `user_id` unique?

Comment: @Fabio I can send the multiple notification message to same user, message_data table userid field is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select
  m.*, -- m.user_id
  IF (SUM(s.status) > 0, 1, 0) has_un_read,
  SUM(s.status) unread_messages_count
From message_data m
INNER JOIN message_status s on m.id = s.data_id
Group By m.id
having SUM(s.status) > 0
```

If `status` field has more than one state other than `0` and `1` then you can do that:

```
Select
  m.*,
  IF(SUM(IF(s.status = 1, 1, 0)) > 0, 1, 0) has_un_read,
  SUM(if(s.status = 1, 1, 0)) unread_messages_count
From message_data m
INNER JOIN message_status s on m.id = s.data_id
Group By m.id
```

**UPDATE**

In case you want to distinguish un read messages from every device:

```
Select
  m.*,
  s.device_id,
  IF (SUM(s.status) > 0, 1, 0) has_un_read,
  SUM(s.status) unread_messages_count
From message_data m
INNER JOIN message_status s on m.id = s.data_id
Group By m.id, s.device_id
having SUM(s.status) > 0
```

Comment: Works but risky if you introduce different status besides read/unread.

Comment: @wajeeh Will it result , A specific user's unread message count ?

Comment: Not so risky because the `status` field only can be `1` or `0` as he asked. @mroman

Comment: @Kaleeswaran now it counts, you can remove last `having` condition to view all users who has or hasn't unread messages.

Comment: @wajeeh if I specify 4 for read status, How can I identify "has_un_read" and  "unread_messages_count" ?

Comment: @Kaleeswaran, you are welcome, You can do it in the `if` condition like that: `if(s.status = 4, 1, 0)` .

Comment: If a notification message is read in at-least one device, It should be considered as read(User read that message from any one of the devices that he logged-in),  I want to identify the each user's,  unread notification message count. What is the change that needs to be done on this query ?

Comment: @Kaleeswaran it is better to ask a new question to clarify the answer, any way you have to add `device_id` to the `group by`, and in this case you must add it (`device_id`) to the `Select` results.